Best pratice to construct a CustomException with a custom message
I have a CustomException class that inherits from Exception, so I'm trying to understand the best practices to construct such an object. This exception would need to construct its own exception message based on the error code it receives, this is what I have so far
public class CustomConnectionException : Exception
{
    public string CustomErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomErrorMessage { get; set; }

    internal CustomConnectionException(string message) : base($"Error during connection: {MatchErrorMessage(errorCode)}") {
        Code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        CustomErrorCode = ParseErrorCode(message);
        CustomErrorMessage = MatchErrorMessage(CustomErrorCode);
    }
}

My problem is the way we have to call :base(message) to set the actual message of the exception object, which means my current code doesn't work since I still don't have the errorCode. To construct the message error, I first need to parse the error code from the original message, and then match the error with the MatchErrorMessage method. What's the best practice to do something like this? Do I make one method to combine both methods that returns the errorMessage? Do I set Message twice?

Is MatchErrorMessage() static?

just add static method for creating it and make constructor  private

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1949309/1043380

Yes it is static. I saw that as an option as well, but then is it okay to set CustomErrorCode in that same static method?

You can't, since a static method cannot access instance members.

As @Selvin suggested, use a static factory method and make the constructor private. The constructor accepts the already parsed/matched custom error codes and messages:
public class CustomConnectionException : Exception
{
    public string CustomErrorCode { get; }
    public string CustomErrorMessage { get; }

    private CustomConnectionException(string message, string code)
        : base($"Error during connection: {message}")
    {
        Code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        CustomErrorCode = code;
        CustomErrorMessage = message;
    }

    // Factory method
    public static CustomConnectionException Create(string message)
    {
        string customErrorCode = ParseErrorCode(message);
        string customErrorMessage = MatchErrorMessage(customErrorCode);
        return new CustomConnectionException(customErrorMessage, customErrorCode);
    }

    private static string ParseErrorCode(...) { ... }
    private static string MatchErrorMessage(...) { ... }
}

You would create an instance like this:
var exception = CustomConnectionException.Create(rawMessage);

The properties can be made read-only (getter-only).

If you were doing a single value update, it would be possible to make your MatchErrorMessage method static and then you could just call it in the base call.  However, since you need an intermediate processing step, and want to retain the value, that isn't exactly practical.  I would consider just updating the value.
public class CustomConnectionException : Exception
{
    public string CustomErrorCode { get; set; }

    public CustomConnectionException(string message) : base() {
        Code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        CustomErrorCode = ParseErrorCode(message);
        Message = MatchErrorMessage(CustomErrorCode);
    }
}

You could consider making a method that gets the value directly from the message, but then you would need to process a second time for the ErrorCode to retain so I'm not sure it is worth it.
